# Help updating and getting apps on Lubuntu

Tags: software-installation, lubuntu

I'm getting back into Linux distributions.  I need assistance with getting and updating applications in Lubuntu.  (ie. Outlook type programs, Open Libre, Firefox, etc.)  This may be too generic but I forgot a lot. Thank you in advance for your time and patience on this matter.

Comment: Have you tried Synaptic package manager?

Comment: One of my problems, used to be able to manage programs through that application.   Lost my touch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your terminal, and install Synaptic:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

After install it should be placed somewhere in menu, like *Administration -> Synaptic* and with it you can manage, install and update whatever packages you want. [Here's](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) the nice tutorial how to use it.

There's also "Software Center" app. It might be considered easier to install new apps with it.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-software-center
```

And other way to update everything:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Already installed... does not seem to want to accept  (?) anything else.  Click on a app/program all it wants to do is remove it, no update, no "apply" - does not highlight.

Comment: Will have to attempt at this later.

Comment: Perhaps you somehow managed to start Synaptic without root's priviledges? It won't highlight "Apply" in such case, but should give a warning at start. Try "Run" command in Lubuntu's main menu and enter `gksu synaptic`.

Comment: The packages that were being highlighted were packages already installed.  That was the reason for it not highlighting the "apply" action.  Many apologies.  Also, got rid of the Lubuntu linux and attempted to install Kali.  To a RAID configuration.  Challenging!  Will not boot up, card needs to have its drivers(?).  For some reason the Linux distribution installs but will not run, even with the boot loader.  The RAID card accepts the install.  It is showing as a total RAID drive.  It shows as mounted... suggestions?